# Is it true that $(x-1)e^{(x-1)^k-x^k}\le 1$ for $k=2,3,4,...$?

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions

I wonder if it is ture that $(x-1)e^{(x-1)^k-x^k}\le 1$ for $k=2,3,4,...$?

Since definitely, this function tends to 0 as $x$ tends to $\infty$. I wonder if 1 is a uniform bound. And I checked it is true for $k=2$ by taking derivate. But I am sure for larger $k$.

Use Mathematica, I found this function decays very fast. But I don't know how to prove its upper bound. Maybe by induction?

Answer (score 1):

If $x\leq 1$, it is trivial, so consider $x>1$. In this case $-(x-1)^k+(x-1)^{k+1}+x^k-x^{k+1} = (x-1)^k(x-2)-x^{k}(x-1)<0$ (compare terms). Hence $e^{-(x-1)^k+(x-1)^{k+1}+x^k-x^{k+1}}<1$. You proved that inequality holds for $k=2$ so let's suppose that it holds for some $k\geq 2$. Then,
\begin{align}
(x-1)e^{(x-1)^k-x^k}&\le 1 \Rightarrow \\
(x-1)e^{(x-1)^k-x^k}e^{-(x-1)^k+(x-1)^{k+1}+x^k-x^{k+1}}&< 1 \Rightarrow\\
(x-1)e^{(x-1)^{k+1}-x^{k+1}}<1.
\end{align}

So your inequality is true, by induction.

PS I didn't actually check it holds for $k=2$. And I am not claiming this is the easiest proof.

Answer (score 0):

*This is not an answer since based o numerical simulations*.

Consider that you want to maximize, with respect to $x$,  function $$f_k=(x-1)\,e^{(x-1)^k-x^k}$$ As you noticed, for $k=2$ the problem is simple : the maximum happens for $x=\frac 32$ and, for this value, $$f_2=\frac 1 {2e^2}\approx 0.0676676$$

For $k=3$, the problem is still simple since $$f'_3=-e^{(x-1)^3- x^3} \left(6 x^2-9 x+2\right)$$ cancels for $x=\frac{1}{12} \left(9+\sqrt{33}\right)\approx 1.22871$ and, for this value, $$f_3=\frac{1}{12} \left(\sqrt{33}-3\right) e^{-\frac{9+\sqrt{33}}{8}}\approx 0.0362123$$

For $k=4$, the problem is still simple since $$f'_4=-e^{(x-1)^4- x^4} \left(12 x^3-24 x^2+16 x-5\right)$$ cancels for $x=\frac{1}{3} \left(2+\frac{\sqrt[3]{13}}{2^{2/3}}\right)\approx 1.16042$ and, for this value, $f_4\approx 0.0261852$.

For larger values of $k$, $f'_k=0$ implies solving a polynomial equation of degree $k-1$ and this starts to be tedious (and even infeasible for $k>5$. But numerically, this does not make any problem and we can get the following results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
k & f_k^{(max)} & x^{(max)} \\
2& 0.0676676 & 1.50000 \\
 3&0.0362123 & 1.22871 \\
 4&0.0261852 & 1.16042 \\
 5&0.0206210 & 1.12492 \\
 6&0.0170135 & 1.10238 \\
 7&0.0144805 & 1.08673 \\
 8&0.0126040 & 1.07523 \\
 9&0.0111581 & 1.06642 \\
 10&0.0100097 & 1.05946
\end{array}
\right)$$